# After wrapping the arrow function, why is the function executed immediately?

Tags: javascript

I am making an app with react native.
If there is no touch response on a current screen, I want to action that automatically advances to the next screen after 5 seconds.

If a button is pressed or input text is entered, I am thinking of clearing setTimeout and counting 5 seconds again.
So I wrapped the functions to put in onPress and onChange that I have in screen.
However, it works as if the button was pressed.
How should I wrap it?...
I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

```js
//ReceiptScreen
...
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
    clearTimeout(this.nextScreenTimer);
  }

handleSendPress = () => {
    if (isValidEmail(this.state.email)) {
      this.props.sendEmailReceipt(this.state.email, this.props.order);
    } else {
      Alert.alert(
        null,
        [
          {
            text: 'close',
            onPress: () => null,
          },
        ],
        {cancelable: true},
      );
    }
  };

handleScreenTimeout = func => {
    console.log('what', func);
    clearTimeout(this.nextScreenTimer);
    this.nextScreenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.handlePressClose();
    }, 5000);
    func();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.nextScreenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.handlePressClose();
    }, 5000);
  }
....

render() {
....
            <InputButton
              placeholder={'example@gmail.com'}
              value={this.state.email}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({email: text})}
              loading={this.props.isEmailReceiptFetching}
              onPress={this.handleScreenTimeout(this.handleSendPress)}
            />
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the following onPress handler

```
onPress={this.handleScreenTimeout(this.handleSendPress)}
```

to be a function that calls your function within it as below

```
onPress={() => this.handleScreenTimeout(this.handleSendPress)}
```

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with your help. Thank you so much :)
What is the difference between the above two? Can you tell me which part of javascript i should study??

Comment: onPress expects a function to be called. You have provided a function call expression. If it returned another function then it will be fine. This is the normal way of doing it by wrapping your function call with another function to make it a callable function again.